# Traversing a binary tree and squaring each element

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I'm hoping someone can help me understand binary trees for my upcoming CS course. To be more specific, I was wondering if anyone could help me on this problem: "Return a tree where all its items have been squared"

This is my class Tree:

```
clas Tree(object):
 def __init__(self, entry, left=None, right=None):
        self.entry = entry
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def __repr__(self):
    args = repr(self.entry)
    if self.left or self.right:
        args += ', {0}, {1}'.format(repr(self.left), repr(self.right))
    return 'Tree({0})'.format(args)
```

So if I have a Tree named t, where t is defined as:

`t = Tree(1,Tree(2,Tree(3)),Tree(4,Tree(5)))`

I want to return `t` as `Tree(1,Tree(4,Tree(9)),Tree(16,Tree(25)))`

So I came up with this function that returns me a squared Tree, but I want to get rid of the "None"

```
def square_tree(tree,fn):
    if(tree == None):
        return tree
    else:
        tree.entry = fn(tree.entry)
        map_tree(tree.left,fn)
        map_tree(tree.right,fn)
    return tree
```

output: Tree(4, Tree(9, Tree(16), None), Tree(25, Tree(36), None))

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are they supposed to be doubled or squared? You say doubled, but the examples are squared...

Comment: Oh, it's suppose to be squared, not doubled.

Comment: TheodrosZelleke was confident enough to edit your question, but I'm not sure - are you supposed to return a new tree, or modify the existing one?

Comment: @japreiss, good point -- I didn't consider the difference -- Sorry if it's wrong -- but tree traversal is still required

Answer (score 2):

Trees are recursive structures. The easiest way to write tree manipulation programs is usually recursion.  So think about the recursive step.

You have a tree and you want to square all the elements.  So you need to:

- square the root element
- square all the elements in the left and right subtrees

That should be enough of a hint since it's homework...

Answer (score 1):

after

`t = Tree(1,Tree(2,Tree(3)),Tree(4,Tree(5)))`

t is

`Tree(1, Tree(2, Tree(3), None), Tree(4, Tree(5), None))`

The class repr is displaying the None leafs. If you don't want it to, fix your repr.